# Why am I not able to update my sql database using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'functions/delivered.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
});
```

This is the ajax code and I am trying to update my database

functions/delivered.php:

```
<?php
$db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","restaurant")
if(isset($_POST['onum'])){
    $onum=$_POST['onum'];
    $query="UPDATE `revenue` SET `payment`='y' WHERE onum=$onum";
    $db->query($query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you checked that view reach at delivered.php or not ?

Comment: Please describe what's not working. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happened? What error messages are you getting? Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your post request only has one key on it, `action`.  There is no `onum` key included.

Comment: Also please note that your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: `$db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","restaurant")` < you didn't close that off with a `;` and should have thrown you a parse error notice for it.

Comment: didn't throw a parse error, fixed it but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You're not sending an `onum` parameter in the AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var onumValue = $("#onum").val();
        var ajaxurl = 'functions/delivered.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue, onum: onumValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
});
```

Replace `$("#onum")` with the actual selector for the input that contains the value you want to send to PHP.

Comment: You missed something for the "php" side of things. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775331/why-am-i-not-able-to-update-my-sql-database-using-ajax#comment105694774_59775331) about that.

Comment: Could just be a copying error, your comment seems to be sufficient for that typo.

Comment: Could be, but we've seen more than our share of those.

Comment: Either way, the comment is enough. Putting it in the answer doesn't add any value.

Comment: Ok. Well, let's see what the OP has to say. They seem to not be responding or have logged out.

Comment: I really don't care. Typo-squashing is for comments.

Comment: I tried putting action instead of onum but it still doesn't work

Comment: Add the HTML to the question.